# Node js connecting to port in Wamp

Tags: node.js, apache, http, server, wamp

I tried to create my own "server" in Node.js and connecting it to my WAMP port 8888.
But somehow I dont get anything back not the response on the localhost:8888 page not even the console.log?

Even nothing happens when I use a different port...

```
    var http = require('http');

function onRequest(request, response){
    console.log("A user made a request" + request.url);
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write("Here is some data");
    response.end();
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
console.log("Server is now running...");
```

Can somebody help me in to the right way?

Greetz
Jens

Comment: How is your wamp server configured? On which port does it listen? How does it connect to your node.js server?

Comment: It is listening to port 80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you need this .htaccess file in the document root folder of your WAMP server:

```
# .htaccess file in document root.
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes -MultiViews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteRule ^(.+) http://localhost:8888/$1 [P]

</IfModule>
```

Now any HTTP request, like `http://localhost/any/path/you/want` will be redirected to port `8888`.

And of course your apache should listen on different port than `8888`, you can keep the default `80` port.

Comment: Hmm this doesnt work for me.. So wierd I just want a simple Node.js server on port 8888 or an other port

Comment: And what is the issue about WAMP?

Answer (score 0):

Ah it works fine now
I Had to change some settings in my WebStorm editor

http://prntscr.com/9tdako

But why I had to change app.js to server.js?